# Execute PHP Mysql query on the basis of select option value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select input having several options in it as html and I want to execute a query on the basis of a selected value in the dropdown list.

```
<select name="test">
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="banana">banana</option>
<option value="mango">mango</option>
</select>
```

I want to execute the following query with a criterion value selected in the above drop down list.

```
<?php $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblsession where sessionid='".$_REQUEST['test']."'"); ?>
```

pls help.

Comment: Is your `<select>` within a `<form>`? Are you `POST`ing or `GET`ing? Hard to help you if you only provide a small snippet like this.

Comment: I am not using get of post coz I want to do it on change, but unfortunately I dont know ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in this same page your going to have to use some javascript so you can be capable of working on AJAX. 
So here's the code for the first page:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="test" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Bannana">Bannana</option>
  <option value="Bannana">Mango</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="para"><b>What you will excute will be listed here...</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is getuser.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('host','username','password','db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"db");
$sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['apple'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['bannana'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['mango'] . "</td>";
  
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```